# Flags are declined because an edit was made afterwards

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive

I flagged a question on Stack Overflow as 'rude or abusive' because it contained some inappropriate words.

Shortly afterwards, the question was edited, removing these words, and so my flag was declined when it was later reviewed by a moderator.

I am a bit annoyed that this has now added to my 'declined flags' count, even though my flag was entirely legitimate!

I think that there should be a new category for flags – instead of just 'helpful' or 'declined', there should be something like 'made unnecessary through an edit to the post'.

Comment: There are actually 3 categories for closed flags, but I think this type of flags can only be "helpful" or "Declined". Please also note that if you can correct problem yourself (like edit out f-words) flag to request moderator to do it should be declined.

Comment: honestly, the only people that care about declined flag counts are new flaggers (and it's normal. You're new to this, so haven't seen the kink in the system yet). Yes it sucks, but you'll see that the ratio of declined to helpful will soon become so low you won't care. As long as you keep flagging, of course :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an edit can be made that removes the offending portions without otherwise affecting the meaning of the post, then a rude/abusive flag is inappropriate.

That's what happened in this case. The original poster used an expletive as an intensifier (which is rather common in colloquial English), and [the edit (revision #4, by Zaid Masud) simply substituted that one word for a different one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59000043/revisions). The post's meaning was not changed. The post was not *inherently* rude or abusive.

The purpose of flags is to bring content to a moderator's attention. A moderator is not required to make an edit: you can do that yourself, as can all other users. There is no reason to flag things when you can handle them yourself.

For spam and rude/abusive flags, there actually *is* a third dispensation option, beyond "helpful" and "declined". These types of flags can also be "disputed". However, as I mentioned above, your flag on that question was rightfully declined, as the post was not intrinsically rude or abusive, and did not need to be deleted by a moderator.